# Angular component name same as HTMLelement allowed?

Tags: angular

Is it allowed to generated an Angular component that has the same name as an HTML element?
E.g.: I have created an Angular component 'button'. When I create my button template I want to use html button element in but it seems that, instead of referencing html element, it wants to reference itself as element. The strange part is that compilation gives no errors but when I run my app I am getting "This page is having a problem". No further information is available on the page.
This is my template:

```
<button [ngStyle]="{'background-color': bgcolour}" class="button">{{text}}</button>
```

Comment: According to the [styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#component-custom-prefix), you should use a prefix, to *prevent element name collisions with native HTML elements*. That's exactly what you have here, a name collision with a native HTML element, where unexpected things can happen. But I also find it weird that the build succeeds but you get such an issue at runtime. Can you prepare a Stackblitz?

Comment: @JSONDerulo, thanks for the quick reply. I am not sure what a Stackblitz is. Can you guide me?

Comment: It's a tool where you can reproduce an issue and share the code with others: https://stackblitz.com/